# ping OK, nslookup OK, wget locally OK, remote HTTP false

Tags: linux, centos, internet

I'm trying to access `http://domain.com/test.html` from internet, but getting error

Server is running CentOS

I'm using DSN hosting (yandex.ru) for `domain.com`

Ping server by ip = OK

Ping server by domain = OK === nslookup = OK

`wget http://domain.com/test.html` locally = OK (apache is configured OK)

Server have following `iptables`:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTAB                 LISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:s                sh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-ho                  st-prohibited
```

UPD: `iptables -nL`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255
ACCEPT     esp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     ah   --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:631
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Please recommend what else should I check?

Comment: result of running "iptables -nL" would be more helpful;

Comment: Off hand, your iptables doesn't seem to permit HTTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your firewall is blocking port 80. Try opening it with

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

If that works then save the current config

```
service iptables save
```

which will update the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file so that next time the service starts port 80 will remain open.